# Terraform - Adding specific users to a specific group

Tags: azure-active-directory, terraform

I have a 2 csv files named "_member.csv" and "_groups.csv".

Content from _member.csv :

```
first_name,last_name,department,job_title
Albator,Albator,Exploitation,Integrateur d'exploitation
Bingo,Bingo,Exploitation,Ingenieur de production
Cresus,Cresus,Etudes et developpements, Analyste developpeur
```

Content from _groups.csv :

```
members_groups
adm-xxx
exp-xxx
cod-xxx
tec-xxx
met-xxx
svc-xxx
```

My resource to create users :

```
resource "azuread_user" "Terra-Aad-User-Member" {
  for_each = { for user in local.azure_members : user.first_name => user }

  user_principal_name = format(
    "%s%s@%s",
    substr(lower(each.value.first_name), 0, 1),
    lower(each.value.last_name),
    local.domain_name
  )

  password = format(
    "%s%s%s!",
    lower(each.value.last_name),
    substr(lower(each.value.first_name), 0, 1),
    length(each.value.first_name)
  )
  
  force_password_change = true

  display_name = "${each.value.first_name} ${each.value.last_name}"
  department   = each.value.department
  job_title    = each.value.job_title
}
```

My resource to create groups :

```
resource "azuread_group" "Terra-Aad-Group" {
  for_each = { for group in local.azure_groups : group.members_groups => group }

  display_name     = format("%s", lower(each.value.members_groups))
  security_enabled = true
}
```

My resource to add users to groups :

```
resource "azuread_group_member" "Terra-Aad-Member-In-Group" {
  for_each = { for u in azuread_user.Terra-Aad-User-Member : u.department => u... if u.department == "Exploitation" }
  
  group_object_id  = values(azuread_group.Terra-Aad-Group).0.object_id
  member_object_id = each.value.id
}
```

The provider :

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azuread = {
      source = "hashicorp/azuread"
      version = "=2.28.1"
    }
  }
}

provider "azuread" {
  tenant_id = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
}

data "azuread_domains" "Terra-Aad" {
  only_initial = true
}
```

My variables.tf

```
locals {
  domain_name = data.azuread_domains.Terra-Aad.domains.0.domain_name
  azure_members       = csvdecode(file("${path.module}/_member.csv"))
  azure_groups = csvdecode(file("${path.module}/_groups.csv"))
}
```

When I launch 'terraform plan', I have this error :

```
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on groupmember.tf line 5, in resource "azuread_group_member" "Terra-Aad-Member-In-Group":
│    5:   member_object_id = each.value.id
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value is tuple with 2 elements
│
│ This value does not have any attributes.
```

Is it possible to automatically add all users who have the department 'Exploitation' to the group 'adm-xxx'? The problem is in the line 'member_object_id = each.value.id' I may need a conditional expression but I don't know exactly what that line is.

Does anyone have an idea?

---

---

Ok. So I added a null_resource to get all the ids of my users who are on the "Exploitation" department like this :

```
resource "null_resource" "Id-Department" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "az ad user list --filter \"department eq 'Exploitation'\" --query \"[].id\" -o tsv"
    interpreter = ["PowerShell", "-Command"]
  }
  depends_on = [azuread_user.Terra-Aad-User-Member]
}
```

I modified my resource azuread_group_member like this :

```
resource "azuread_group_member" "Terra-Aad-Member-In-Group" {
  for_each = { for u in azuread_user.Terra-Aad-User-Member : u.department => u... if u.department == "Exploitation" }
  
  group_object_id  = values(azuread_group.Terra-Aad-Group).0.object_id
  member_object_id = null_resource.Id-Department

  depends_on = [null_resource.Id-Department]
}
```

Now I get this error :

```
│ Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│
│   on groupmember.tf line 13, in resource "azuread_group_member" "Terra-Aad-Member-In-Group":
│   13:   member_object_id = null_resource.Id-Department
│     ├────────────────
│     │ null_resource.Id-Department is object with 2 attributes
│
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "member_object_id": string required.
```

What I need is to take all the results of the command in null_resource to this: member_object_id = null_resource.Id-Department
Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: According to the provided image, the map structure is indeed missing an `id` attribute. There also does not appear to be anything analogous to it in that image. You are probably missing those values in your CSV.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). It would be great to have those csv files or representative data as text.

Comment: I have edited as you recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, it seems most simple just to extract the groups to a list. Then for `azuread_group`, you can just use [toset](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/toset). Once that is done, you can reference this group by the group name in the object. So within `azuread_group_member` you use the [for expression](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/for) to get only members that are have "Exploitation" - you can reference their `member_object_id` by `each.value.object_id`. And you can get the `group_object_id` from the set-built `azuread_group` objects.

```
locals {
  azure_groups  = [for v in csvdecode(file("${path.module}/_groups.csv")) : v.members_groups]
  azure_members = csvdecode(file("${path.module}/_member.csv"))
}

resource "azuread_user" "Terra-Aad-User-Member" {
  for_each = { for user in local.azure_members : "${user.first_name}-${user.last_name}" => user }

  user_principal_name = format(
    "%s%s@%s",
    substr(lower(each.value.first_name), 0, 1),
    lower(each.value.last_name),
    local.domain_name
  )

  password = format(
    "%s%s%s!",
    lower(each.value.last_name),
    substr(lower(each.value.first_name), 0, 1),
    length(each.value.first_name)
  )

  force_password_change = true

  display_name = "${each.value.first_name} ${each.value.last_name}"
  department   = each.value.department
  job_title    = each.value.job_title
}

resource "azuread_group" "Terra-Aad-Group" {
  for_each = toset(local.azure_groups)

  display_name     = lower(each.value)
  security_enabled = true
}

resource "azuread_group_member" "Terra-Aad-Member-In-Group" {
  for_each = {
    for k, v in azuread_user.Terra-Aad-User-Member :
    k => v if v.department == "Exploitation"
  }

  group_object_id  = azuread_group.Terra-Aad-Group["adm-xxx"].object_id
  member_object_id = each.value.object_id
}
```

As an aside, I have no idea how a `null_resource` is relevant here. You should have all the information you need without it.